# Return name from list to PHP variable

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I think my structure may be wrong on this page but I've gone too far to change it and now trying to make the best of a bad situation.

I have a large list of items in drop down.

an example is :

```
 <li><a href="conversion.php?conversionType=accelerationAngular">Acceleration - Angular</a></li>
```

What I'd like to use is something like :

```
<h4><?php

        if ($conversionType == null){
            echo "Please select a category";
        }else{
            echo "Current Category : " . $conversionType;
        }
        ?>
    </h4>
```

to display what the current selected category is.  The above works but it doesn't display "Acceleration - Angular", it displays accelerationAngular which of course is how I've named the values to be passed onto another page.

Is there a way I can extract the name of the li element ?

Comment: Why don't you use a hashed array to store the values and names to display?

Answer (score 2):

For me, I would have a PHP array with all the LI values and labels:

```
$list = array(
    'accelerationAngular' => 'Acceleration - Angular',
    'someOtherValue' => 'Some Other Label',
    // And more...
);
```

Then output the list:

```
<?php foreach($list as $k => $v): ?>
<li><a href="conversion.php?conversionType=<?php echo $k ?>"><?php echo $v ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Then for your header:

```
<h4><?php echo isset($list[$conversionType]) ? $list[$conversionType] : 'Please select a category' ?></h4>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I used the array and the header part but havent used the for each li as my structure has various different levels etc.  Works fine though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, not sure if you are hand-coding your HTML, but if you are, you could rewrite your code as follows

```
<li><a href="conversion.php?conversionType=Acceleration%20-%20Angular">Acceleration - Angular</a></li>
```

so that the same string that appears as the text of the link gets passed to the server as the conversionType parameter.

Comment: I can;t do this as it means changing too many things.  thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="conversion.php?conversationType=<?=urlencode($title='Acceleration - Angular')?>"><?=$title?></a></li>
```